# Get user details when login using grails spring security rest plugin

Tags: grails, spring-security-rest

I am using grails spring security plugin. When i am loggging in, i am getting username and token and roles as json response. Along with these properties i want to get some other properties like firstname, lastname etc. How can i get these values as json response when logging in to the app using grails spring security rest plugin?

Comment: As far as i know you need to add claims to the token with user details ,you can use `springSecurityService?.currentUser`, and get user details from there

Comment: at the time of login itself i want to get the details instead of making another request to get logged in user

Comment: @Jagadeesh did you resolve this?

Comment: No. I have done separate rest call if the user object is null in the local storage

Answer (score 1):

You can add token claims, i generally would advise against modifying the plugin code,but

You can add desired details by adding new claim in

`AbstractJwtTokenGenerator`(or preferably by overriding it)

```
JWTClaimsSet generateClaims(UserDetails details, String serializedPrincipal, Integer expiration) {
        JWTClaimsSet claimsSet = new JWTClaimsSet()
        claimsSet.setSubject(details.username)

        log.debug "Setting expiration to ${expiration}"
        Date now = new Date()
        claimsSet.setIssueTime(now)
        use(TimeCategory) {
            claimsSet.setExpirationTime(now + expiration.seconds)
        }

        claimsSet.setCustomClaim('roles', details.authorities?.collect { it.authority })
        claimsSet.setCustomClaim('principal', serializedPrincipal)
        //claimsSet.setCustomClaim('username', details.getUsername()) //added customized user name claim
        log.debug "Generated claim set: ${claimsSet.toJSONObject().toString()}"
        return claimsSet
    }
```

**Note :** subject in `claimsSet.setSubject(details.username)` already contains the username

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/latest/docs/):

> If you want to render additional information in your JSON response,
>   you have to:
>
> - Configure an alternative userDetailsService bean that retrieves the additional information you want, and put it in a principal object.
> - Configure an alternative accessTokenJsonRenderer that reads that information from the restAuthenticationToken.principal object.

Additional info about [userDetailsService](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html)  and [accessTokenJsonRenderer](https://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/1.5.2/docs/gapi/grails/plugin/springsecurity/rest/token/rendering/AccessTokenJsonRenderer.html)